# ASPNET MVC 4 editor template for jquery file upload (blueimp)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, editortemplates

I'm trying to create an EditorTemplate for MVC4 for all my file inputs, I'm using blueimp jquery-file-upload plugin, and it's working great, however I have some doubts with the editor template:

I have a class to bind to the editor template like this:

```
public class FileUpload
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string TempFileName { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public bool Modified { get; set; }
...
public class MultiFileUpload : List<FileUpload>
{
}
```

and in my ViewModel where I want to upload a file I have this:

```
public class TestModel
{
     [Required]
     [MaxLength(3)]
     public MultiFileUpload File { get; set; }
}
```

this is my EditorTemplate (/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MultiFileUpload.cshtml):

```
@model MultiFileUpload

<div class="file-upload">
    <ul class="list-group files-list">
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        { 
            <li class='list-group-item'>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Id)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Deleted)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].TempFileName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].FileName)
                @Model[i].FileName
                <a href="#" class="delete pull-right" style="margin-right:-15px; text-decoration:none;"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a> 
            </li>
        }

    </ul>

    <span class="btn btn-default fileinput-button">
        <i class="icon-plus"></i>
        <span>Add File</span>
        <input type="file" name="" data-url="api/fileupload" data-single="false" />
    </span>
</div>
```

**I want to have client validation of my File property in TestModel (MaxLength would be the number of files the user can upload), how can I do that?**

**or, is there any other recommended way of doing this file upload kind of modular in mvc4?.**